# Launching specific fragment of an activity from a background service on Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-service

I have an app with a working background service running on a custom made Android 5 device (so I can use regular background service and I am ok with it)

My goal is that background service can send some kind of intent start or open the app and specific fragment from the activity.

My activity_main.xml looks as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

And the MainActivity.kt looks as follows

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
  

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        val intent = Intent(this, BackgroundService::class.java)  // Service restarts from here!
        this.startService(intent)

    }
}
```

I have tried adding intent to just start the app from the service based on the advice from stack overflow

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)  // Service restarts from here!
this.startService(intent)
```

but it didn't work...

I have also added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

In AndroidManifest

So it looks like the problem is twofold, how to start/open activity and how to switch to the correct fragment.

I will be thankful for any advice

Comment: Where are you indicating which fragment should be started? I see nothing.

Comment: `this.startService(intent)` You have that twice. The second one should be startActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add new task flag:

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)  // Service restarts from here!

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

this.startActivity(intent)
```